# iOS, how to make word-clipping line break mode in UITextView

Tags: uitextview, word-wrap

At first I think it's easy but I don't find a way to do it.

I'm making a UITextView to display some text content, some works are pretty long. So by default of textView.textAlignment, some line left big blank because next word is long. Like this:

```
I'm typing some words here
to explain long word 
willcause big blank
because in UITextView. It
makes some line left big
blank.
```

What I want is line break by clipping word, it's an pretty old style but I still want it, like this:

```
I'm typing some words here
to explain long word will-
cause big blank because in
UITextView. It makes some 
line left big blank. I wa-
nt the line break by word 
and just add '-' in the b-
reaking word.
```

At first I see UILabel has lineBreakMode property but I found UITextView don't have it at all. What I do now is use NSTextAlignmentJustified for textView.textAlignment, but it also cause very big blank between words.

Is it possible to display in 'word-clipping' way?

Thanks.